# Unable to invoke-command from Server 2012 R2 to Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, powershell, windows-server-2012

I am trying to run an `invoke-command` from a Windows Server 2012 virtual to a Windows 8 virtual.  The machines are in the same domain and on the same subnet.  I have ran the `Enable-PSRemoting -force` command on the Windows 8 machine and received the following output:

```
WinRM has been updated to receive requests. 
WinRM service type changed successfully. 
WinRM service started.

WinRM has been updated for remote management. 
Created a WinRM listener on HTTP://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on this machine. 
WinRM firewall exception enabled.
```

However, when I go back to the server and try to `invoke-command`, I get this error:

```
[WINDOWS8VIRTUAL] Connecting to remote server WINDOWS8VIRTUAL failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (WINDOWS8VIRTUAL:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Need to find the cause of `WinRMOperationTimeout`

Is your windows 2012 server & windows 8 able to communicate with (ping) each other?

Is there a policy (group, etc.), `FIREWALL RULE` that might be preventing the connection?

Please provide more details and try these tests:

- Provide the results of ipconfig /all from both machines?
- Check results of hostname, whoami, etc. Does name match your PS input?
- In AD (Active Directory) is your windows 8 machine listed in computers or another organizational unit?
- Check your current WinRm configs in PS: `WinRM get WinRM/config`
- Check that WinRM default ports (HTTP:595, HTTPS:5986) are open in firewall config.
- Tests whether the WinRM service is running on a local or remote computer.
- Run in PS: `Test-WSMan -computer "YOUR_TEST_PC_NAME"`

Here are some more sources:

- [Web Services-Management (WS-Management)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849876.aspx)
- [Windows Server 2012 - Server Manager Troubleshooting Guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13444.windows-server-2012-server-manager-troubleshooting-guide-part-ii-troubleshoot-manageability-status-errors-in-server-manager.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable CredSSP (Credential Security Support Provider) to pass credentials

On your workstation, run this command:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer *.yourdomain.com -Force
```

This configures your system to pass CredSSP authentication to any remote computer on yourdomain.com - in place of '*.mydomain.com' you can use '*' to the delegate computer to enable passing CredSSP to any computer or the FQDN of the server (example: 'someserver.mydomain.com') to allow the passing of SSP credentials ONLY to that server.

On your server, run this command:

```
Enable-WSMaCredSSP -Role Server –Force
```

This configures your server to accept CredSSP authentication from any remote computer.

your Invoke-command then will then take the additional switch of:

```
-Authentication CredSSP
```

example:

```
$cred = get-credential
Invoke-Command -credential $cred -Computer "TheServer" -Authentication CredSSP -ScriptBlock {do a thing}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command on the Windows server:

```
winrm e winrm/config/listener
```

and double check the host and port on which the WinRM service is listening.

The default HTTP port is 5985, and the default HTTPS port is 5986.

Then make sure it's enabled by:

```
winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP @{Enabled="true"}
```

---

To print all the settings, run: `WinRM get WinRM/config`.

To test the local service, run in PS: `test-wsman localhost`.

Docs page: [Installation and Configuration for Windows Remote Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

If you're connecting to Amazon EC2 instance, make sure you've unblocked the necessary ports in your security group for that instance.